# Why would the US require a marriage certificate for visa a application?

Tags: visas, usa

My sister wanted to go to visit our uncle in the US in 2007. She went through a process of nearly a year to obtain a visa. One of the more peculiar things they wanted from my parents was a copy of their marriage certificate. I could understand the proof of residence, although my father questioned whether the fact you own a house or were renting should influence it.

Eventually, with more paperwork than a G8 summit, she did get a 10-year visa but I could not help but wonder what exactly my parent's marital status had to do with obtaining a visa?

Comment: Was the marriage certificate relevant to prove relations between your sister and your uncle ? Did either of your parents change names due to marriage?

Comment: Aaah yes, I see my uncle is my mother's brother and my mother did take my father's surname of course. I can't believe I did not see it. If you post it as an answer I will upvote it. I clearly great over-estimated the complexity of this problem.